Why a different standard for the unborn in the Old Testament?
In Exodus 21:12 (Saint Joseph Edition of the New American Bible) it says:

Whoever strikes a man a mortal blow must be put to death.

Also, in Leviticus 24:17:

Whoever takes the life of any human being shall be put to death.

Yet, in Exodus 21:22 it says:

When men have a fight and hurt a pregnant woman, so that she suffers a miscarriage, but no further injury, the guilty one shall be fined as much as the woman's husband demands of him, and he shall pay in the presence of the judges.

This seems to be saying that even though the men killed the baby, their lives are not demanded in exchange for the baby's life.  Is the OT putting the life of the unborn at a lower level than the born, so that the former is not worth the latter?

The Hebrew word referring to miscarriage is "Nepel/Nefel/Nephel" (Strong's 5309), found in Psalm 58:8 & Job 3:16
Psalm 58:8

May they be like a slug that melts away as it moves along,
like a stillborn child that never sees the sun. (NIV)

Job 3:16

Or why was I not hidden away in the ground like a stillborn child,
like an infant who never saw the light of day? (NIV)

In Exodus 21:22, the Hebrew word used is "Yatsa" (Strong's 3318). which means "to go or come out". This term doesn't specify whether the outcome is alive or death. The NIV translates it as "birth prematurely". The final judgement depends on the outcome, as detailed in Exodus 21:22-25.

22 “If people are fighting and hit a pregnant woman and she gives birth prematurely but there is no serious injury, the offender must be fined whatever the woman’s husband demands and the court allows. 23 But if there is serious injury, you are to take life for life, 24 eye for eye, tooth for tooth, hand for hand, foot for foot, 25 burn for burn, wound for wound, bruise for bruise. (NIV)

The rules are:

If there is no serious injury and the child survives, the offender must pay a fine as demanded by the woman's husband and allowed by the court. (Exodus 21:22)
If anyone dies as a result, whether it's the man involved in the fight, the pregnant woman, or the child, the offender must be put to death. (Exodus 21:23)
If someone is hurt, the offender will receive a penalty commensurate with the injury. (Exodus 21:24-25)

The Lord does not undervalue an unborn child. David praises the Lord in Psalm 139:13-16

13 For you created my inmost being;
you knit me together in my mother’s womb.
14 I praise you because I am fearfully and wonderfully made;
your works are wonderful,
I know that full well.
15 My frame was not hidden from you
when I was made in the secret place,
when I was woven together in the depths of the earth.
16 Your eyes saw my unformed body;
all the days ordained for me were written in your book
before one of them came to be. (NIV)

In Jeremiah 1:5, The Lord calls Jeremiah saying:

“Before I formed you in the womb I knew[a] you,
before you were born I set you apart;
I appointed you as a prophet to the nations.” (NIV)

Even in his dispair, Job says in Job 31:14-15:

14 what will I do when God confronts me?
What will I answer when called to account?
15 Did not he who made me in the womb make them?
Did not the same one form us both within our mothers? (NIV)

Therefore, the Lord is the creator of both the born and unborn. In Him, there is no discrimination.

Very interesting answer.  Yes, the translation makes a big difference!

Hope this helps clarify your thoughts.

Indeed, and Butterworth's answer also illustrated this point, although that answer doesn't make it explicit.  I didn't realize the translations could differ so dramatically on quite an important point.  I'm also surprised the Catholic church gave my Bible with this translation the imprimatur.

I'm accepting this answer because it most directly answers my question, and brings out an ambiguity in translation I was not aware of.  Thanks again for a very interesting answer.

In short, because the unborn did not share the same legal status as the living in the Law
If men strive, and hurt a woman with child, so that her fruit depart from her, and yet no mischief follows: he shall be surely punished, according as the woman's husband will lay upon him; and he shall pay as the judges determine. And if any mischiefs follow, then thou shalt give life for life, Eye for eye, tooth for tooth, hand for hand, foot for foot, Burning for burning, wound for wound, stripe for stripe. -Ex 21:22-25 KJV)
This verse indicates that if a man is in a physical altercation with another man and the other man’s wife steps in to help and is injured causing a miscarriage, he is required only to pay a fine.  If the fetus were considered a full person, he would be punished more severely as though he had taken a life. “If any further mischief occurs”, (death of the woman), then the offender was to be executed for his crime “life for life’’.
To this, respected scholars John H. Walton, Victor H. Matthews and Mark W. Chavalas agree:
“The Exodus law hinges on whether there is any further harm to the mother beyond the loss of the fetus and imposes a fine based on the claim of the husband and the pronouncement of the judges. The object of the fine is to compensate for the injury to the mother rather than the death of the fetus.”—IVP Bible Background Commentary Ex 21:22)
Often in discussing this passage the initial explanation for why God did not require a death penalty for the death of the unborn is ‘because it was an accident’. Yet, this is not so easily treated; because the death of the mother required the execution of the man, “life for life”, and it was just as much accidental. The only explanation for the differing penalties is that the mother and unborn did not share the same legal status.
Now we must address the controversy of this passage. If one reads an older translation it is pretty obvious the unborn is miscarried through the ordeal, but it is not so clear in some newer translations. For example, the NIV translates ‘born prematurely’ and offers ‘miscarry’ as a possible option; the NET also chose to go this route. This possibly changes the implications of the text.
I have to disagree with their choice based on my own education in Hebrew, as well as many other students. John Walton, OT scholar, makes no apology in his Bible Background Commentary when explaining the passage as a ‘caused miscarriage’ and offers no other option. In fact, I was surprised at his courage to publish such a fact, considering the current temperature of the debate concerning the issue.
I believe he is right in his assessment, for several reasons. First, if this is simply speaking of a premature birth where the child survives what is the man being penalized for? No harm done. Second, the infant mortality rate was high enough under full term normal birth conditions, much less premature distressed conditions. Third, it does not specify or imply the survival of the unborn. For example, it does not specify at what point during the pregnancy the departure occurs, certainly if it occurs early in the pregnancy there is no chance of survival. Lastly, translating this text only becomes an issue of debate when abortion becomes a common social debate for us beginning in the 80s. It becomes apparent our ‘culture war’ has certainly influenced the translation of this text, whereas translations before ‘pro-choice’ vs. ‘pro-life’ felt no need to recruit it to their side of the debate.
The Bible Contains an Abortion Ritual
To further complicate the matter there is an explicit reference to the subject. Numbers 5:11-31 contains an abortion ritual. The reason for terminating the pregnancy? Infidelity. If a husband thinks his wife cheated, but lacks the legal proof, he is to take his wife to the high priest. In this case the woman has come up pregnant among suspicious circumstances. The priest whips up a concoction with water and the dust and ashes from around the altar and makes her drink it. If she is innocent, nothing happens. If she cheated on her husband though, she becomes ill, and the child of infidelity is aborted.
And when he hath made her to drink the water, then it shall come to pass, that, if she be defiled, and have done trespass against her husband, that the water that causeth the curse shall enter into her, and become bitter, and her belly shall swell, and her thigh shall rot: and the woman shall be a curse among her people. And if the woman be not defiled, but be clean; then she shall be free, and shall conceive seed.-Num 5:27-28)
The word often used for “thigh” in Numbers 5 is “yarek” in the original Hebrew. It can mean thigh, loins, genitals or represent offspring. For instance “yarek” is used in Genesis 46:26 to say all of Jacob’s children “which sprang from his loins (yarek).” Judges 8:30 says ““Gideon had seventy sons who went out from his thigh (yarek), for he had many wives.” The NET translator notes points out, “The Hebrew word יָרֵךְ (yarekh, “thigh”) is a euphemism here for the penis.” (Euphemisms are when we soften the explicit nature of something by using a less offensive word to describe the idea, and they are common linguistic devices in all cultures.) As in Genesis 24 when Abraham makes his servant place his hand under his thigh (yarek) and swear an oath, yes he did.
Most modern translations simply translate yarek as “thigh” in Numbers 5, so it may be hard to read the explicit abortion in this kind of artificial subtext caused by later English translations – it is much more explicit in the original Hebrew. It is not her “thigh as in leg that rots or falls away” – it is her “belly” (womb) that swells and “ loins” that falls away. This is not a controversial interpretation at all; scholars agree to the euphemism here, it is simply ignored. Jamison, Fausett and Brown offer no explanation, neither does the beloved Matthew Henry commentary. This passage is so clear to anyone with a basic knowledge of Hebrew it is easier to ignore it than explain it away.
However, Walton, Matthews and Chavalas, has to once again concede to the facts of the text:
“the negative potential results. Suggestions have ranged from a flooded uterus to false pregnancy to pelvic prolapse to atrophied genitalia. Whatever the actual physical manifestations might be, the text clearly indicates that the result is sterility. If the woman has been brought into this process because of pregnancy, it may be that the potion would be expected to induce a miscarriage in the case that the pregnancy came about through illicit behavior”.—Bible Background Commentary Numbers 5:27)
Although they do honestly admit to what the text says, notice the ‘softening’ of it, “induced miscarriage”. They carefully craft their words to avoid the term ‘abortion’ but we grownups know what an induced miscarriage is.
The execution laws differentiate the legal status as well
Genesis 38:24 Tamar's pregnancy was discovered three months after conception, presumably because it was visible at that time. This was positive proof that she had been sexually active. Because she was a widow, without a husband, she was assumed to be a prostitute. Her father-in-law Judah ordered that she be burned alive for her crime. If Tamar's twin fetuses had been considered to be human beings, one would have expected her execution would have been delayed until after their birth. There was no condemnation on Judah for deciding to take this action. (Judah later changed his mind when he found out that he was the man responsible for Tamar's pregnancy.)
If the unborn that she was carrying are not to be regarded as living human beings at the end of her first trimester of pregnancy, then causing their death would not be a great moral concern.
However, if the twin fetuses are to be considered as human persons, then it seems strange that they would be considered of such little value as to allow them to be killed for the alleged sin of the woman carrying them. This same practice persisted through scripture, if a woman conceived through adultery she was executed with no regard for the unborn in her womb.
It is very tempting for me as an Evangelical to pass it off as a cultural ill God just tolerated, much like we do with other portions of scripture that offend our new and improved systematic theologies. However, The Law cited in Exodus and Numbers supposedly come from God, if you believe the biblical claims, which most of us here do. I am forced to accept the unborn did not have the same legal status as the born based on three things: 1. a man was not executed for murder in event of accidently causing a miscarriage but he was executed for murder if the mother died accidently (Ex 21:22-25). 2. The priest was instructed to perform an abortion ritual that God would cause if the child was conceived through adulterous relations (Numb 5:27-28). 3. When adultery was provable the man and woman was commanded to be executed with no temporary stay of execution to provide time for the birth of any possible offspring (Deut 22:22-23, Lev 20:20-21).
It is clearly seen the unborn did not possess the same legal status as the born, the priest were not considered murderers for the ‘God ordained’ abortion and it was not considered murder when executing mother and unborn due to infidelity. If life begins at conception as we traditionally assert, then the previous passages pose serious inconsistencies in the bible. How do we reconcile the fact that the unborn did not have the same legal status as the born, yet life begins at conception, a dilemma indeed.
I suggest you research the term "breath of life" which is used many times to understand why the unborn didn't have the same legal status as the born. It really was about the breath

Interesting.  Yet "the life is in the blood" and the placenta keeps the mother's blood and the unborn's blood separate. Until the child's lungs begin to function at birth the introduction of oxygen and the removal of carbon dioxide is done for the child by the mother. She does, in some sense, breathe for the unborn so I don't know if it's fair to say that the unborn does not have the breath of Life.

+1 for cogent explanation. I wonder about the 'fine' the husband may demand - and whether the amount would be largely based on whether the miscarried fetus was determined to be male. If female, perhaps restitution would be waived? But what if the fetus would have been a firstborn male. And then after the miscarriage, sterility ensued, or only females were conceived? Sticky wicket, especially for that culture.

I think the second two cases distract from the main question, since they also are based on inferences, that at least to me, do not emerge unambiguously from the text.  I think the most helpful answer would more thoroughly address why "miscarriage" is the best translation for "yatsa", besides just appealing to tradition.  Otherwise, if "give birth" is an option, it would be more consistent with the overall passage and the subsequent verses.

I disagree about claiming a 'legal status'. If the woman had a miscarriage because of the altercation by standing between two fighting men, it's obvious this was accidental -- manslaughter. And given that there's no way to tell if a miscarriage occurred because of the fight or from natural causes the man could not be condemned with certainty. This isn't about legal standing of the fetus rather laws on manslaughter.

@KatieRoseMüller I agree the injury to the woman and the child would have been unintentional   Thus penalty would be less severe.  Think also about the city of refuge arrangement

When trying to determine the meaning, it's good to consider other translations too.
Exodus 21:12

(SJNAB) Whoever strikes a man a mortal blow must be put to death.
(KJV) He that smiteth a man, so that he die, shall be surely put to death.
(NLT) Anyone who assaults and kills another person must be put to death.

Leviticus 24:17

(SJNAB) Whoever takes the life of any human being shall be put to death.
(KJV) And he that killeth any man shall surely be put to death.
(NLT) Anyone who takes another person’s life must be put to death.

Exodus 21:22

(SJNAB) When men have a fight and hurt a pregnant woman, so that she suffers a miscarriage, but no further injury, the guilty one shall be fined as much as the woman's husband demands of him, and he shall pay in the presence of the judges.
(KJV) If men strive, and hurt a woman with child, so that her fruit depart from her, and yet no mischief follow: he shall be surely punished, according as the woman's husband will lay upon him; and he shall pay as the judges determine.
(NLT) Now suppose two men are fighting, and in the process they accidentally strike a pregnant woman so she gives birth prematurely. If no further injury results, the man who struck the woman must pay the amount of compensation the woman’s husband demands and the judges approve.

Comparing these (and other) translations of Exodus 21:12 and Leviticus 24:17 makes it more obvious that the death was intentional:

"a mortal blow"
"so that he die"
"assaults and kills"

This is describing a case of murder, deliberately causing someone's death.
And after Exodus 21:12, an exception is given (NLT):

13 But if it was simply an accident permitted by God, I will appoint a place of refuge where the slayer can run for safety.
14 However, if someone deliberately kills another person, then the slayer must be dragged even from my altar and be put to death.

The killer may go to one of several specified cities where he can plead that the death was accidental, not murder, and be allowed to stay.
Presumably this is to prevent further bloodshed when friends or relatives of the deceased decide to take personal revenge.
Now consider Exodus 21:22:

"men have a fight and hurt a pregnant woman"
"men strive, and hurt a woman with child"
"two men are fighting, and in the process they accidentally strike a pregnant woman"

This is a case of manslaughter, unintentionally causing someone's death.
(Even today it's common for the law to distinguish between "cold blooded murder", "hot blooded murder", and "manslaughter".)
Under the exception of 21:12, refuge could be sought, but there are two differences here:

There were two men involved, not one.
Fines, determined by the husband, must be paid, and before a judge.

If the husband (and wife) accept the payment, the case is considered legally settled, and all parties agree that the situation is settled and closed.
Any further action of vengeance would then be considered premeditated cold-blooded murder, not a hot-blooded response.
There is little fear that a feud will develop between members of the two (or three) families, so there is no need for anyone to be exiled to a different city.
The difference in penalties is not a result of having a different standard for an unborn person.
It is having different penalties for deliberate and unintentional deaths, and for different ways of handling situations that would not lead to further bloodshed.

Unintentional death still carries the death penalty in Exodus 21:13, with the place of sanctuary for such killers.  Sanctuary does not apply to intentional murder.  However, in the case of a miscarriage, there is not even a need to flee to sanctuary, suggesting causing the death of an unborn baby is not as serious as killing a born human being.

You make good points. However, the punishment for unintentional manslaughter was exile to a City of Refuge for life (or until the death of the High Priest). So whilst I agree that this case is not the same as intentionally putting to unborn child to death, there is still a difference in the Law between how the death of an unborn child is treated vs a child that has been born. Of course, it used to be a LOT more common to see miscarriages and infant deaths than it is now - so perhaps that is being taken into account here.

+1. Good answer.

@RyanPierceWilliams, taking refuge in another city would not be necessary in this case. The number of people that might want to take revenge is very small, and they have agreed before a judge that the issue is settled.

@RayButterworth still, there is a difference in what is allowed to be asked for in front of the judge.  In the case of manslaughter of the born, the party can ask for the killer's life.  In the case of the unborn, the party can only ask for money.  So, born entails exchanging life for life, and unborn is money for life.  This seems to imply life is not ascribed to the baby until it is born, which, anecdotally, I've heard from Jewish people is their perspective on the abortion debate.

A massive distinction is to be made between the loss of a fetus due to an altercation between two other people which injured the mother and the loss of a fetus by the deliberate decision of the mother because the fetus is unwanted.
